# free(struct variable) doesn't clear previous stored values associated with that variable when I malloc again?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I created a struct like the following:

```
typedef struct header{

    int hc;
    char src[18];
    char dst=[18];
    char reason[15];
    char d[3];
    char m[3];
    char y[4];

     struct measurements{

        char h_ip[17];
         int h_ttl;
         int h_id;
        float h_rtt;

    }HOPS[100];

}HEADER;


INSIDE MAIN: 

               HEADER *head;
                for(...){

                head=(HEADER*) malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
                 .....
                free(head);

                }
```

Will the above malloc automatically allocate memory for the inner struct as well? Also, I'm facing a weird problem here. After I free the header, I'm still able to print the values of **head->HOPS[i].h_ip**. **Should I explicitly free the inner struct as well so that even the values get cleared?**

Comment: Standard warning: do **not** cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends!

Comment: You should read about how the heap and its related functions in C work. Any C book should explain this. SO is not a tutorial site (which you need - no offense!)

Comment: `head=(HEADER*) malloc(sizeof(HEADER));` head is an object, not a pointer ( `HEADER head;` is its declaration)

Comment: Sorry for the typo-edited it! @wildplasser

Comment: @Olaf: So I should just do head=malloc(sizeof(HEADER))?

Comment: Try and then report the warning you eventually get (assuming what you posted is correct)! And then read about data types in C. Focus on `struct`s and _pointers_.

Comment: No the code he posted is not correct. Even after completing main() it would not compile (hint: `sizeof head`)

Comment: @wildplasser: "hint: sizeof head" Where do you see that? `sizeof(HEADER)` is correct, problem is the non-pointer `head`, which removing the cast should reveal even to OP.

Comment: See my first comment. (head is not a pointer, the OP fails to see that)

Comment: @wildplasser: Not just to see ...

Comment: And not just the OP, the answerers too ...

Comment: @Olaf, Thanks a ton!! I did just head=malloc(sizeof(HEADER)) without the typecast! Surprisingly there were no warning and that did the magic. But can you explain why this behaviour?

Comment: Ehm... **then you did not post the correct code**! It should definitively had given a warning. `head` is **not** a pointer

Comment: @Olaf Sorry I missed the *head. I edited the code a wee bit because it was too long. Now edited it.

Comment: Man! you are stressing. Next time you get comments about a failure in your code, review carefully, ask for clarification, but **check** what you posted. You eat up time of people trying to help.

Comment: @Olaf really sorry about that. Apologies!

Comment: I added an answer, think that should summarise my comments and adds vital information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it allocates memory for the inner structure. And you need not free the inner structure separately. 
If you have a pointer defined inside your structure, in that case you have to allocate separately for that pointer member of the structure and free that separately.

Comment: Thanks! Will bear in mind when I use this in future.

Comment: @AbhishekBalajiR: Any C book would have told you that! **Read**!

Answer (score 0):

Consider freeing memory as a black box. All what you know is that after freeing you shouldn't refer to freed memory.

You may find that that memory block still exists and still contains some old values. That's ok: it just was marked as freed and probably it will be used again soon by allocator.

For example when you call malloc again and realized that just allocated block contains values from the old structure. It happens and that's alright. Just use this block as usually.

Answer (score 0):

So, after the problem with the wrong declaration of `head` was resolved:

`free` returns a **previously** allocated memory block to the *heap*. It does not clear anything (for performance reasons). However, you are **not** supposed to access that block anymore afterwards. Doing so results in *undefined behaviour* and might let your computer fly out of the window.

Worst that can happen is ... nothing ... Yes, you might even not notice anything strang happens. However, that does not mean your program run correctly, it just does not show any symptoms.
To catch illegal accesses, you might set the pointer to `NULL` once you `free`d the object it points to. Some operating systems catch accesses to addresses near the *null pointer* address, but there is no guarantee. It is a good practice anyway and does no harm.

For your other question: `malloc` allocates a block of memory large enough to store that many *bytes* you passed as argument. If it cannot, it will return a *null pointer*. You should **always** check if `malloc` & friends returned a valid pointer (i.e. not a *null pointer*).

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
if ( p == NULL ) {
    error: out of memory
}
...
```

Notice the omission of the cast of the result of `malloc`. In C you should not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends (but also elsewhere). As much as you did not for `free(head)`. Both take the same type: `void *`, btw. (so why cast one and not the other?). Note that in C any object pointer can freely be assigned to/from `void *` without cast. **Warning** functions are **no** objects in the C standard!

Finally: `sizeof(HEADER)` returns the size of the `struct`. Of course that include **all** fields. A nested `struct` is a field. A pointer to another struct is a field. For the latter, however note: the pointer itself is a field, but **not** what it points to! If that was another struct, you have to `malloc` that seperately **and also `free` seperately (remember what I wrote above).

But as you do not have pointer inside your `struct`, that is not your problem here. (keep it in mind, if you continue programming, you will eventually need that!)